# snowflake get list of table given the database

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using snowflake jdbc driver to get the list of tables in a given database,
i have 2 prepared statement. I get the `PreparedStatement` from the same `Connection`

```
    PreparedStatement usePrepStatement = con.prepareStatement("use database IDENTIFIER(:1)");
            usePrepStatement.setString(1, database);
            usePrepStatement.execute();
```

and to get the tables from information_schema

```
String sql = "select table_schema, \n" +
                "       table_name, \n" +
                "       table_type \n" +
                "from information_schema.tables where table_catalog = '?'";
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, database);
ResultSet tableResultset = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Here tableResultset is empty. How to I get this query to return the right result

I can query the `current_database()` I see the current database is set to the right value

The above queries works if i use `Statement` instead of `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identifiers are stored in uppercase, so using case insensitive comparison should solve it.Also there is no need to wrap the parameter with `'`:

```
from information_schema.tables where table_catalog = '?'

=>

from information_schema.tables where table_catalog ILIKE ?
```

Comment: Thank you, looks like removing the `'` worked.